# CodeIgniter 4 - turn off display of debugger toolbar - without changing CI_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: debugging, codeigniter-4

CodeIgniter 4 - how to turn off display of **debugger toolbar** - without changing **CI_ENVIRONMENT**?

Changing environment variable **CI_ENVIRONMENT** to **production** will turn off the debug toolbar - but will also **suppress errors**.
I want to still see errors - but I do not want to see the debug toolbar at the bottom of all of my views when in 'development' mode.

Answer (score 7):

You should remove (or comment) the **'toolbar'** filter in **App\Config\Filters.php** as told in the official [CI4 documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/testing/debugging.html#enabling-the-toolbar).

```
public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
    ],
    'after' => [
        //'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add this header with your ajax request

xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", 'XMLHttpRequest');

Answer (score 1):

Removing `toolbar` from `$gloabals['after']` in `app\config\Filters` also do the trick.

Source: https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=76243&pid=375043#pid375043

Answer (score 0):

It can be closed in the following ways:-

1. Set "production" in "/app/.env" file variable.

   ```
   set $_SERVER['CI_ENVIRONMENT'] = 'production';
   ```
2. If "/app/.env" file does not exist in the project. Then create static variables in "/app/Config/Constants.php" file.

   ```
   defined('ENVIRONMENT') || define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); //development
   ```
3. Instead of the above point if you do not want to change the "Environment" value to remove the icon and debug mode, change "/app/Config/Boot/development.php" file variable.

   ```
   defined('CI_DEBUG') || define('CI_DEBUG', false);
   ```
4. Change  "/app/Config/Toolbar.php" file object to remove spefic debug toolbar option.

   ```
   public array $collectors = [
        //Timers::class,
        Database::class,
        Logs::class,
        Views::class,
        // \CodeIgniter\Debug\Toolbar\Collectors\Cache::class,
        Files::class,
        Routes::class,
        Events::class,
    ];
   ```